# Creating Picture Gallery in ASP.NET C# Website in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there any automated way of creating a picture gallery in visual studio 2010 as available in Dreamweaver?

If not could you please suggest how i can achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Download Web Matrix from

http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/

- Choose 'site from web gallery' I believe there are a whole bunch in there. Once you download those and configure you can simply open the same solution in visual studio. 
  This one uses a template to do it - you want 'gallery' instead- but the screen shots here show you how basic it is to get web matrix up and the initial screens you want:

http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/add-a-photo-gallery-to-your-website-using-lightbox-and-javascript